# Entity Framework 4.1 strongly-typed Include doesn't provide IntelliSense?

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I've added: using System.Data.Entity;
and now I don't get an error on compilation of this:

```
var k = db.Countries.Include(e => e.Cities);
```

but I still have to manually go into the database schema and check the current table correct name and copy-paste/type it in the code.
There is no IntelliSense after I use the period:

```
var k = db.Countries.Include(e => e.
```

So, the purpose of all this is questionable since it doesn't really help at all. Typing manually the table name (entity set name) in quotation marks isn't any different than typing it in a lambda expression - except for it is shorter as a string.

Hints?

Comment: Can you try to write this before or after the line above: `var c = new Country(); c.` Does intellisense appear or not after the period?

Comment: Yes, of course it does. I would notice is something is wrong with the IS overall, but it just doesn't recognize the strongly typed form until I use it. If I chain one more include on a completed statement, it then works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the problem is in ReSharper 6 IntelliSense. After turning off ReSharper 6 IntelliSense, the original VS2010 IntelliSense works fine. The bug has been reported.

Answer (score 6):

Seems like your problem will be resolved when you add

```
using System.Data.Entity;
```

to top of your page